Where can I find the 'ivf' access method for creating an index on a vector column?
The GCP docs (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/understand-example-embedding-workflow#create-index) give an example for creating an index on a vector column:
CREATE INDEX complaint_embed_idx ON items
  USING ivf (complaint_embedding vector_l2_ops)
  WITH (lists = 20, quantizer = 'SQ8');

But when trying to run this I get:
[42704] ERROR: access method "ivf" does not exist
When I look at the docs for the pgvector extension (https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#indexing) the only methods mentioned are 'IVFFlat' and 'HNSW'. I tried using IVFFlat, but that gives another error:
[22023] ERROR: unrecognized parameter "quantizer"
I'm using Postgres 15 on Cloud SQL and I have installed the pgvector and Vertex AI integration extensions with:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vector;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS google_ml_integration CASCADE;

What's going wrong?

It seems that this feature of pgvector is not yet released? See: https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/pull/231
